# Is there a systematic way to find a permutation with a power equal to this product of transpositions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I am trying to find an n-cycle, $\sigma$, $n\ge 10$ with 
$$\sigma^k=(12)(34)(56)(78)(9\; 10)$$
For k an integer in a systematic way.

I know the basic facts about powers of $n$ cycles, as in 
$$
\sigma^n=e\\
$$
and $\sigma^{-1}$ just reflects the cycle horizontally. Can I use these?

Comment: What does $k$ mean here ?

Comment: Try showing that if $\sigma=(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)$ for some ordering of the elements, and that $\sigma^k(3)=4$ and that $\sigma^{2k}(3)=3$ that it follows that $\sigma^{2k}(i)=i$ for all $i$ and thus $\sigma^{2k}(0)=1$ is an impossibility.

Comment: @Peter sorry just some integer

Comment: Or, are you perhaps not meaning $(910)$ as a three-cycle, but rather as $(9~\text{ten})$?  If so, then how about $(1~3~5~7~9~2~4~6~8~\text{ten})$ and $k=5$?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean, I wasn't sure how to format it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powering a permutation splits its cycles into smaller ones all of the same length. In particular, this means that $\sigma$ must be a permutation of $\{1,\cdots,10\}$ times a permutation of all numbers from $11$ to $n$. The latter must be something of order $k$ in order to disappear after powering. Without loss of generality, assume $\sigma$ is simply a permutation of $\{1,\cdots,10\}$.

No odd-length cycle can appear in $\sigma$ since the entries of the odd-length cycle would never appear in an even-length cycle of $\sigma^k$, but $\sigma^k$'s even-length cycles include all numbers $1,\cdots,10$.

Thus the cycle type of $\sigma$ must be among the list

- $10$
- $8,2$
- $6,4$
- $6,2,2$
- $4,4,2$
- $4,2,2,2$
- $2,2,2,2,2$

If $k$ is odd it will preserve the cycle type, so it must be $2,2,2,2,2$. Then the only solution is

$$ \sigma=(\color{DarkOrange}{12})(\color{Red}{34})(\color{Purple}{56})(\color{Blue}{78})(\color{Green}{9\,10}). $$

If $k$ is even, then powering kills $2$-cycles, leaving only types $10$ and $6,4$ as possibilities.

Type $10$ powers to type $2,2,2,2,2$ precisely if $k$ is divisible by $5$ but not $2$. One solution is

$$ \sigma=(\color{DarkOrange}{1}~\color{Red}{3}~\color{Purple}{5}~\color{Blue}{7}~\color{Green}{9}~\color{DarkOrange}{2}~\color{Red}{4}~\color{Purple}{6}~\color{Blue}{8}~\color{Green}{10}). $$

Type $6,4$ powers to type $2,2,2,2,2$ precisely if $k$ is divisible by $2$ and $3$ but not $4$, and

$$ \sigma=(\color{DarkOrange}{1}~\color{Red}{3}~\color{Purple}{5}~\color{DarkOrange}{2}~\color{Red}{4}~\color{Purple}{6})(\color{Blue}{7}~\color{Green}{9}~\color{Blue}{8}~\color{Green}{10}) $$

is a solution.

I've colored the solutions in order to illustrate the interlacing process I used to create them. In order to obtain *every* possible solution, simply rearrange $(12)(34)(56)(78)(9\,10)$ by permuting the cycles and transposing their entries, then interlace as above. (Apologies to the color-blind.)